# Can a REST GET request have multiple response per object

Tags: rest

I have a person calculation table (lets say id, personName, calculation)  which save some calculations per user. I want to develop a REST service for that object. so if I make a GET call `/rest/personcalculation/{personName}`, I want to a response like following;

```
[
{ "name" : michael,
"calculation" : 23
},
{ "name" : michael,
"calculation" : 45
},
{ "name" : michael,
"calculation" : 12
}
]
```

Is this a valid standard for developing RESTful services?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, GET on `/rest/person/{personid}/calculation` would be a better service url for your scenario. And the response for that can be a list(or array) of the calculation associated with that person:

```
[
{ 
"calculation" : 23
},
{ 
"calculation" : 45
},
{ 
"calculation" : 12
}
]
```